# How to convert the darknet yolo model to keras?

Tags: python, keras, darknet, yolo

I am using yad2k to convert the darknet YOLO model to a keras .h5 format. I have yolov3-voc.cfg, yolov3.weights, and yolov3.cfg all in the directory above the one that contains the yad2k script. When I run the following command:

```
python3 yad2k.py -p ../yolov3-voc.cfg ../yolov3.weights model_data/yolov3.h5
```

or:

```
python3 yad2k.py -p ../yolov3.cfg ../yolov3.weights model_data/yolov3.h5
```

I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yad2k.py", line 271, in <module>
    _main(parser.parse_args())
  File "yad2k.py", line 90, in _main
    cfg_parser.read_file(unique_config_file)
  File "/Users/tobykrieman/anaconda/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 718, in read_file
    self._read(f, source)
  File "/Users/tobykrieman/anaconda/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 1080, in _read
    raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
file: '<???>', line: 7
'<!DOCTYPE html>\n'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your darknet `.cfg` files likely aren't correct. They should look something like this:

```
[net]
batch=128
subdivisions=1
height=227
width=227
channels=3
momentum=0.9
decay=0.0005
max_crop=256

learning_rate=0.01
policy=poly
power=4
max_batches=800000

angle=7
hue = .1
saturation=.75
exposure=.75
aspect=.75

[convolutional]
filters=96
...
```

(taken from https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/cfg/alexnet.cfg)
Your `.cfg` file seems like it has HTML in it.

Answer (score 8):

You should try the instructions in this [Github repository](https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3), which is a "A Keras implementation of YOLOv3"

```
git clone https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3.git
cd keras-yolo3
wget https://pjreddie.com/media/files/yolov3.weights
python convert.py yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights model_data/yolo.h5
python yolo.py   OR   python yolo_video.py [video_path] [output_path(optional)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot convert YOLOv3 to Keras model using YAD2K. This is because YOLOv3's configuration file has a `[shortcut]` header. The yad2k.py file has no method to handle this header as it was written in the times of YOLOv2 (which doesn't have this layer/header).

However, in your case, you seem to be reading a different kind of configuration file, which apparently has a `<!DOCTYPE html>\n` tag. But in any case, even if you try it with the YOLOv3 cfg, it won't work for the reason i mentioned above. Tried it myself!